# Multiple boot options in efibootmgr

Tags: boot, bios, efibootmgr

I have removed window (built in my pc) and installed ubuntu.
So, technically it should have only one boot option which is ubuntu but running efibootmgr
it shows three commands.
Here is snap
[picture of command line of running command efibootmgr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQm7K.png)

Should i remove the other 2 options.

Comment: If you have CD/DVD, I would keep them all. The drive boot is typically a fallback boot that uses /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi or may be an old BIOS boot setting. You can see details of boot entry with `sudo efibootmgr -v`

Answer (score 0):

No. These options are automatically added by the system firmware. They will only re-appear on the next boot.